# Create directory inside symbolic link (window)

Tags: php, windows-phone-7, symlink

I want to create folder and read files inside the symbolic link directory in windows environment.

Here is my code for create folder. I want to create folder "20210203" inside the documents directory.

[image]

Here is the folder in to windows

[image]

Comment: I don't think that links in windows behave like folders. If you open your command prompt and write `dir` you will see that your "documents folder" is named `documents.lnk`. Furthermore, you cannot change into that directory. Therefore I believe that the path you use will be invalid

Answer (score 0):

Windows supports symlinks, this is the command:

```
MKLINK C:\dir1 c:\dir2 /D
```

`/D` means this is a directory symlink.

This works for network drives as that's what I used it for myself.